# Show Croatian letters (čćšđž) using substring in php

Tags: php, substring

My DB tables are in `utf8_general_ci`, web page header is defined `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

I do not have problems with reading whole words ex. "Čovjek" etc, but now I need function to foreach whole croatian alphabet and I am using

```
$slova = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $category['name']);
$firstLetter = substr(strtolower($slova), 0, 1);
```

As result I am getting always ? for each croatian letter

here is my code (foreach loop)

```
<?php $letter = 'prvo';
    foreach ($categories as $category) :
      $slova = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $category['name']);
      $firstLetter = substr(strtolower($slova), 0, 1);
        if ($firstLetter !== $letter) :
          if ($letter !== 'prvo') :
            echo '</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 bottom-margine">';
                endif;
            $letter = $firstLetter;
                if($firstLetter == 'Z'){
                    $firstLetter = $firstLetter.',Ž';
                }
                if($firstLetter == 'c'){
                    $firstLetter = $firstLetter.',Ć,Č';
                }
                if($firstLetter == 's'){
                    $firstLetter = $firstLetter.',Š';
                }
                else {
                    $firstLetter;
                }
            echo '<div class="index-font">'.strtoupper($firstLetter).'</div>';
        endif;
            echo '<div class="font-style"><a href="kategorije/'.$category['id'].'/'.$category['link'].'">'
                        .$category['name'].'
                        </a></div>';
    endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php. https://3v4l.org/jq61S vs. https://3v4l.org/2juRg

Comment: Why would you want to change the internal encoding (`iconv`) if you are already using UTF?

Comment: @arkascha that is only code from test. With or without iconv result is same

Comment: Most likely you are trying to use 8bit string functions on a multibyte string which will certainly chop characters into two, so leave invalid characters. Either use the multibyte variants directly `mb_...()` functions, or use php's overloading feature for these functions, so that a call to `substr()` actually calls `mb_substr()` in background.

Comment: Ok, thx... with mp_ is working, but there is error in foreach logic, because with mp_ on each loop which starting with c or č or ć php add additional letter group as C Ć Č and again if there is word with c or č he create letter group C Č... but on international alphabet hes working ok

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking there. Could you please rephrase that, or post a simple script example that I can replicate the issue with?

Comment: @chris85 code is above. Now I can read croatian letters but if I have in DB values "Big, Band, Brother" foreach will sort all results with B under 1 category (Big, Band,Brother), but if I have "Cat, Čovjek, Cloud" foreach will create 3 Categories C for Cat, Č for Čovjek and C for Cloud and result is mixed. I hope so that you understand me

Comment: So you want all the `C` variations as one `C`?

Comment: Yes, plus that Z have Ž, and S have Š, and D have Đ

Comment: Hmm that's a bit of a different question, I'd suggest there are regexs you could use (character classes) so all subsets are considered the same.